# How to query with Hibernate Envers for chart data

Tags: postgresql, analytics, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-envers

I'm using Hibernate Envers and PostgreSQL to keep track of entity history and I'd like to take advantage of this to chart data for analytic purposes. For example, I'd like to campionate a count of entities during a certain period and I was able to produce a query to obtain this from Envers tables, i.e.

```
with recursive times(t) as (
    values 
        (1524700800000) 
    union all 
    select 
        t + (3600 * 1000) 
    from 
        times 
    where 
        t < 1527811200000
), 
revisions(t, n) as (
    select 
        times.t, 
        max(r.id) 
    from 
        times 
        left outer join REV r on r.timestamp <= times.t 
    group by 
        times.t 
    order by 
        times.t
) 
select 
    r.t, 
    count(r.n) 
from 
    revisions r 
    left outer join Order_AUD o on o.rev <= r.n 
    and o.revtype <> 2 
    and (
        o.revend > r.n 
        or o.revend is null
    ) 
group by 
    r.t 
order by 
    r.t
```

and I get this result set

```
-----------------------+---
2018-04-26 00:00:00+00 | 0
2018-04-27 00:00:00+00 | 2
2018-04-28 00:00:00+00 | 5
2018-04-29 00:00:00+00 | 8
2018-04-30 00:00:00+00 | 8
2018-05-01 00:00:00+00 | 9
2018-05-02 00:00:00+00 | 9
```

which is correct as it shows the growing number of orders each day.

Note: I'm using `ValidityAuditStrategy` to have the `revend` column available.

Then, if I want to filter the aggregation e.g. counting only orders in a certain status, I can add a predicate to the join clause:

```
select 
    r.t, 
    count(r.n) 
from 
    revisions r 
    left outer join Order_AUD o on o.rev <= r.n 
    and o.revtype <> 2 
    and (
        o.revend > r.n 
        or o.revend is null
    )
    and o.status = 'pending'
```

Here I'm using CTE and runtime tables, which I can't use with the Envers API, so my question is:

How can I achieve equivalent result with the Envers API (if possibile at all)?